# Why my battery won't charge

Tags: ford, battery, escape

I have a 2004 escape and it has new battery and new alternator and tried a new ignition cluster.  And can't get my battery to charge. I notice that before it gets so low that the car starts stalling b4 it dies my airbag light starts flashing.  I took it to mechanic and put a new alternator on it and redid the plug and he got sick so I had to get my car back when I got it back and still didn't charge but now my radio stays on all the time I'm wondering if you might hook the club back up backwards or is there something may be wrong with my PCM I'm at my wit's end please help

Answer (score 1):

I infer from your statement that the vehicle runs, but when running the battery is not charged and instead discharges. This can occur if any one or more of the following exist:

- The battery is bad. Even new or "it was just tested good" batteries can be bad and refuse to accept charging current.
- One or more of the electrical cables between the battery, the alternator, or the car's body or engine block (ground) is defective. The defect may not be visible to the eye.
- One or more of the electrical connections at either end of the above cables are bad. Again, the defect may not be visible to the eye.
- The alternator may be bad. Even a just-installed alternator may be bad.
- If there's a separate voltage regulator, it may be bad. Sometimes the voltage regulator is mounted on the alternator.

I don't know what you mean by "ignition cluster" and "PCM."

All in all: you should find a shop competent in the diagnosis and repair of automobile electrical systems, and have them diagnose and repair what's wrong.